# How to clear a textbox based on a checkbox using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, checkbox, webforms

I am trying to code in javascript (to avoid validation triggers at the server) to clear a text box if the checkbox associated with it is unchecked.

I have this code ...

```
    <input type="checkbox" id="chkOTHER" onclick="document.getElementById('txtOtherFlag').value='';" />
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtOtherFlag" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" CausesValidation="True" ValidationGroup="ValidationGroup1"></asp:TextBox>
```

The problem is the Javascript inside the checkbox is not triggering to remove the value in the text box. Even if this worked, it's incorrect as it would blank out the text box every time the checkbox is triggered whether it is checked or not.

I need to resolve this in the client side only.

Thank you

**[UPDATE]**

As requested, here is my entire ASPX page minus sections not relevant to the problem ...

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Attendance/Attendance.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="ClassAttendance.aspx.cs" Inherits="Attendance_ClassAttendance" 
        Title="Class Attendance" Culture="en-AU" %>
    <%@Register TagPrefix="tecnq" TagName="ResetPassword" Src="~/Controls/ResetPassword.ascx" %>
    <%@Register TagPrefix="tecnq" TagName="ContactLog" Src="~/Controls/ContactLogKPI.ascx" %>

    <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">

...
we go now to my panel and table ...
...

    <asp:panel ID="PanelPreStart" runat="server" Visible="false" Enabled="false" >
    <table runat="server" id="tblPreStart" style="width: 649px; height: 543px; border-right: activecaption thin solid; border-top: activecaption thin solid; border-left: activecaption thin solid; border-bottom: activecaption thin solid; background-color: white; background-image: none;">

...
we now go to the checkbox and textbox controls within a customvalidator ...
...

        <tr>
            <td id="tdDocs" runat="server" style="table-layout: fixed; visibility: visible; overflow: auto; border-collapse: separate; font-size: 12pt; vertical-align: top; text-align: left; font-weight: bold; font-family: Arial; background-color: transparent; width: 799px; background-image: none;" colspan="2">
                <strong>What documents will be required for today's tasks?<br /></strong>
                    <span style="font-size: 9pt">(Please ensure supporting documentation is attached)</span>
                <asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator12" runat="server"
                        ErrorMessage='Tick one of the "Documents required today" section tick boxes.' OnServerValidate="CustomValidator12_ServerValidate" ValidationGroup="ValidationGroup1" Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="9pt">*</asp:CustomValidator><br />
                    <table style="width: 651px; font-weight: bold; font-size: 10pt; font-family: Arial;">
                        <tr>
                            <td style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: Arial; height: 22px; font-weight: bold; width: 247px;">
                                <strong>
                                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkJSEA" runat="server" Text="JSEA" Width="200px" Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="10pt" ValidationGroup="ValidationGroup1" /></strong></td>
                            <td style="height: 22px; font-weight: bold; font-size: 10pt; width: 278px; font-family: Arial;"><asp:CheckBox ID="chkRISKA" runat="server" Text="Risk Assessment" Width="200px" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="10pt" ValidationGroup="ValidationGroup1" /></td>
                            <td style="height: 22px; font-weight: bold; font-size: 10pt; width: 121px; font-family: Arial;"><asp:CheckBox ID="chkWMS" runat="server" Text="Work Method Statement" Width="200px" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="10pt" ValidationGroup="ValidationGroup1" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="font-size: 12pt; width: 247px; font-family: Arial; height: 22px;">
                                <strong>
                                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSOP" runat="server" Text="Safe Operating Procedures" Width="200px" Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="10pt" ValidationGroup="ValidationGroup1" /></strong></td>
                            <td style="height: 22px" colspan="2">
                                <label><input type="checkbox" id="chkOTHER" runat="server" />Other </label>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtOtherFlag" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" CausesValidation="True" ValidationGroup="ValidationGroup1"></asp:TextBox>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
            </td>
        </tr>

...
and much further down is the javascript/jquery stuff, after the end of the Panel above and after the content placeholder
...

    </table>
    </asp:panel>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            $("#chkOTHER").change(function(){
                if(!$(this).prop("checked")){
                    $("#txtOtherFlag").val('');        
                }
            });
        });

...
some other javascript functions here which work
...

//        $(document).ready(function() {
//            $("#chkOTHER").change(function() {
//                if ($(this).not(":checked")) {
//                    $('.TheTextBox').val("");
//                } 
//            });
//        });
    </script>
</asp:Content>
```

I have both Karl's and Juan's variant jquery functions above.

Any help with this has been greatly appreciated and taken on board. I've tried them all so far and I still cannot get that textbox from clearing when I un-tick the checkbox.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Maybe `onclick="if(!this.checked) this.form['txtOtherFlag'].value='';"`.

Comment: That didn't work as per the error I commented below. Same error, different method ie: form[]. My controls are not in a form. They are in a table within a panel. Maybe the "runat" is causing problems here? But I need that for intellisense in c#

Comment: Nasty, form controls should be in a form as it provides some really good fallback options if your code fails. Anyhow, if you aren't using a form then `onclick="if(!this.checked) document.getElementById('txtOtherFlag').value='';"` or in jQuery: `onclick="if(!this.checked) $('txtOtherFlag').val('');"`

Comment: @RobG I tried both variants you've explained above and again no joy. The IDs have not rendered to defaults like CheckBox1, TextBox1, etc. They are still the same names as mentioned above. I'll post my latest attempts below where Karl is commenting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider unobtrusive JavaScript by using a jQuery selector in reaction to the checkbox's check changed event, like this:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtOtherFlag" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
         CausesValidation="True" ValidationGroup="ValidationGroup1" 
         CssClass="TheTextBox" />

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#chkOTHER").change(function() {
        if ($(this).not(":checked")) {
            $('.TheTextBox').val("");
        } 
    });
});
```

Note: I added a `CssClass` attribute to allow for jQuery to more easily select the correct `TextBox`, in case there are or will be more on the form. Class selectors allow you to avoid the potential server control name mangling that happens when using master pages and the ugly embedded code block syntax (`<%= ... %>`).

Comment: Thanks Karl, but can you elaborate where I should place that bit of jquery? And what calls it? I noticed there is no event on the textbox control to fire it, so how does it work? New to all this sorry.

Comment: @LoftyWofty - the `$(document).ready(function()` fires when the DOM of the page is finished loading, which immediately wires up the click event to the `chkOTHER` check box. When the check box checked value is changed, then the code inside of the `$("#chkOTHER").change(function() {` line fires and it runs the `if ($(this).not(":checked")` logic, which is determining if the check box is unchecked; if so then finally `$('.TheTextBox').val("");` clears the text in the text box.

Comment: So now there is `$(this).not(":checked")` vs `!this.checked`. ;-)

Comment: @RobG - Understood, wanted to keep it using jQuery throughout the example as not to confuse the OP, but I appreciate the input. :-)

Comment: @KarlAnderson Thanks for the explanation, but how to I use this? I already have <script type="text/javascript"> section and I placed it inside that but it still does not work or fire up. Is it because the type should be jquery and not javascript?

Comment: @LoftyWofty - yes, you need a reference to the jQuery library, like this: `<script src="pathTojQuery/jquery.min.js"       type="text/javascript"></script>`. This script reference needs to occur before the script block with document ready function.

Comment: @KarlAnderson. Sorry to bother you. I already have <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script> and then followed by <script type="text/javascript"> and some javascript calls for other events (working)... and then your code at the end. I noticed a bracket missing by the way. Sorry still does not work.

Comment: @LoftyWofty - no worries, post your markup and JavaScript/jQuery and I will help you put it in the right place and hopefully get it working soon. :-)

Comment: @LoftyWofty - good catch on the missing right paren (`)`), updated answer.

Comment: @LoftyWofty - please post all of the code into the question, this is too difficult to view in comments.

Comment: @LoftyWofty - so if you comment the other solution and then uncomment mine, then all you need to do is to put the `CssClass` value of `theTextBox` on your `TextBox` and you should be good to go.

Comment: @KarlAnderson. With all due respect did you read the above UPDATE? Because I did exactly that - placed the CssClass and nope still does not work. Maybe the jquery scripting should be inside the panel? Maybe those double-quotes and single quotes in your code should be consistent? Not trying to be "smart" here, but something so simple can be so difficult is beyond me. Here is a link which is so simple I am about to cry. http://www.jasondahlin.com/WebSite2/CodeSnippets/Javascript-Update-TextBox-When-Checkbox-Checked.aspx But I don't want to use a form. I cannot change it

Comment: @LoftyWofty - try this in your page: `<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#chkOTHER").change(function() {
                if ($(this).not(":checked")) {
                    $('.TheTextBox').val("");
                } 
            });
        });
    </script>
    <input type="checkbox" id="chkOTHER" checked="checked" value="Other" />
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtOtherFlag" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
                 CausesValidation="True" ValidationGroup="ValidationGroup1" 
                 CssClass="TheTextBox" Text="Blah blah blah" />`

Comment: @LoftyWofty - completely understand your frustration, please try the above code alone in the page and see if it works, I am wondering if you have some conflicting jQuery/JavaScript in your page.

Comment: @KarlAnderson. It works! BUT... it only works if I remove the runat="server". I knew that had something to do with it. Unfortunately I need it to run on the server as I have other checks on it and intellisense won't work for it either. Obvious question - can we have javascript running for controls that have runat server? Thank you anyway Karl. I am giving you the Answer reply and point.

Answer (score 1):

you can see if the checkbox is checked before clearing your text:

```
onclick="if(this.checked===true){document.getElementById('txtOtherFlag').value=''};" />
```

Comment: Hmmm shouldn't that be '==' instead of '==='? Also it did not work anyway .. Message: 'document.getElementById(...)' is null or not an object

Comment: You need to check the id of your TextBox. My bet is that it is changed on the actual webpage and this is why you are getting that error.

Comment: @LoftyWofty - the triple equals is valid JavaScript, because JavaScript will try to convert types to other types in order to "help" you. For instance, in JavaScript `2 == "2"` will return `true`, because JavaScript converts the number `2` into a string and then does the comparison resulting in `"2"` equaling `"2"`. Whereas with the triple equals (`===`) operator, `2 === "2"` will return `false`, because the conversion of the number `2` to a string does not happen. Hope this helps.

Comment: @LoftyWofty to be able to use this remember to set the ClientIDMode="Static" in your textbox so the ID doesn't change when rendered

Comment: @JuanC. The control is <asp:textbox> which does not have that ClientIDMode property. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

First add ClientIDMode ="Static" to your textbox like this

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtOtherFlag" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" CausesValidation="True" ValidationGroup="ValidationGroup1"></asp:TextBox>
```

this is to avoid using a class in your textbox and to be able to use your textbox with the id "txtOtherFlag"

then, remove the onclick event from your checkbox

```
<input type="checkbox" id="chkOTHER"/>
```

now add the following inside your < script > tag

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $("#chkOTHER").change(function(){
        if(!$(this).prop("checked")){
            $("#txtOtherFlag").val('');        
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: As I said above ... Warning 25 Validation (ASP.Net): Attribute 'ClientIDMode' is not a valid attribute of element 'TextBox'.

Comment: yes it is, i use it some times: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: And what do you mean "add inside your tag"?

Comment: sorry, i didn't noticed that it was not displayed correctly that script tag

Comment: Sorry mate, it still does not work. Here is what I did ...<label><input type="checkbox" id="chkOTHER" runat="server" />Other </label>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtOtherFlag" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" CausesValidation="True" ValidationGroup="ValidationGroup1"></asp:TextBox> and inside my <script type="text/javascript"> I placed your code (not confident it would not work without the class mentioned earlier by Karl).