# Php Clear textbox when user checks a checkbox

Tags: javascript, php, html, checkbox

at the moment I am trying to add some functionality for a user to be able to submit an anonymous suggestion. I am trying to clear a textbox that contains the users name when the user checks the checkbox. However my code does not clear the checkbox when checked. is there a way to clear the checkbox before the form is submitted?

Thanks

```
<div>
    <label style="display: inline-block; margin-left: 10px; letter-spacing: 2px; color: #007A8E;"> 
        <div align="left"><b>Name:</b> </div>
    </label>
<div align="left">
    <input type="checkbox" style=" margin-left: 110px; outline: 1px solid #0078AE; " name="Anonymous" value="Anonymous" onClick="CheckAnon">
</div>
    <label style="margin-left: 2px; color: #0078AE;">
    <div align="left">Anonymous</div>
    </label>
<div align="left">
<? 
function CheckAnon()
{
    if(isset($_POST['Anonymous']) == 'Anonymous')
    {
        $anonFirstName="Anon";
        $anonLastName="Anon";
    }
    else if (isset($_POST['Anonymous']) != 'Anonymous')                                 
    {
        $anonFirstName = $firstName;
        $anonLastName= $lastName;
    } 
}
?>
</div>
</div> 

<div align="left">
    <input name="firstname" style="height: 34px; width: 268px; margin-left: 10px; margin-top: 5px; color: #007A8E;
    border: 1px solid #dedede; -moz-border-radius: 5px; -webkit-border-radius: 5px; border-radius: 5px;" type="text"
    value="<? echo $anonFirstName?> <? echo $anonLastName?>">
</div>
```

Comment: I think you are confusing PHP and JavaScript here.

Comment: Your question is confusing. Are you referring to the checkbox or the textbox? BTW your php code does not do what you want it to do... The variables are inside a function, thus only work within the function, not outisde (global context in this case)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to clear a textbox based on a checkbox using Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19944351/how-to-clear-a-textbox-based-on-a-checkbox-using-javascript)

Comment: Hi I was referring to the checkbox. when this is checked then the TextBox should clear. I still very much a beginner with regards to web development, as i understand it PHP is server side and anything that needs to be done client side should be JavaScript or Jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this at client side using jquery or javaScript.

Assume this text box:

```
  <input type="text" id="fname" />
```

JavaScript Method:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function clearTextBox() {

      // Code to clear textbox on Checkbox tick

      var textname = document.getElementById("fname"); //get textbox id
      textname.value = ""; // clear the textbox
    }
 </script>
```

Comment: Hi thanks Rahul this worked perfectly, I removed my PHP function and used the code you provided, thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in PHP as you want.

But, doing it in jQuery is quite simple.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
  $("#Anonymous").change(function(){
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      $("#firstname").val('');
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: No he doesn't need JQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing clientside scripting (JavaScript in your case) with what the server receives (PHP).
The function you call:

```
onClick="CheckAnon"
```

Does not exist on the client. Also use: onClick="CheckAnon();"

There are more problems in your code. I advice you to use Firefox and look in the errorlog of javascript. This will help you a lot to trace the bugs.

Also make sure you understand what happens in the client (browser), and the server (after you post a form)
I think you need to clear that up first before you start clearing textboxes with JavaScript)